# Using leaflet for multiple popups

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, react-leaflet

Following this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562383/using-leaflet-library-to-output-multiple-popup-values) to make multiple popup values that shows the year, region, flat_type and resale value for each marker but it keeps giving me this error

> Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Here's what I followed from the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562383/using-leaflet-library-to-output-multiple-popup-values) with my own changes. `df` refers to the dataset. There are 2 different datasets in the leaflet plot.

```
 output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data=df()) %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addPolygons(data=adm, weight = 3, fillColor = "white", popup=popup)%>%
        addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), popup = paste("Year of Purchase:", df$year, "<br>",
                                                                          "Region", df$region, "<br>",
                                                                          "Flat-Type",df$flat_type,"<br>",
                                                                          "Resale Price:",df$resale_price , "<br>",
                                                                          "Address:", toupper(df$geoAddress)))%>%
        addMarkers(data=mrt,lat = ~lat,lng = ~lon,label=mrt$mrt_station,icon = mrticon)
```

This is my data

```
 head(headlinedata,1)
    month       town flat_type block      street_name storey_range floor_area_sqm flat_model lease_commence_date resale_price year month1
1 2007-01 ANG MO KIO    5 ROOM   259 ANG MO KIO AVE 2     04 TO 06            135    MODEL A                1982       345000 2007      1
      region                                  address      lat      lon                             geoAddress
1 North_East BLOCK 259 , ANG MO KIO AVE 2 , SINGAPORE 1.368554 103.8316 259 ang mo kio ave 2, singapore 560259
```

Here's my code

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: When I try to run the shiny app this error is shown "Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". That only occurs when I add the code to show the popup information

Comment: Don't know if it is the problem, but in the leaflet code you are using both `df()` (a reactive) and plain `df` (a variable). Are you sure that both "exist"?. For debugging purposes, I'd ttry first of all to put a `browser()` before `leaflet(data=...` and check if all the needed data are ""available.